# Scheme removing nested duplicates

Tags: scheme, racket, nested-loops

So I'm programming in scheme and made a function that removes duplicated but it doesn't work for nested. I can't really figure out a good way to do this, is there a way to modify the current code I have and simply make it work with nested? lists?

Here's my code

```
(define (duplicates L)
  (cond ((null? L)
         '())
        ((member (car L) (cdr L))
         (duplicates (cdr L)))
        (else
         (cons (car L) (duplicates (cdr L))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your procedure jumps over elements that exist in the rest of the list so that `(duplicates '(b a b))` becomes `(a b)` and not `(b a)`. It works for a flat list but in a tree you might not have a first element in that list but a list. It's much easier to keep the first occurrence and blacklist future elements. The following code uses a hash since you have tagged `racket`. Doing this without a hash requires multiple-value returns or mutation.

```
(define (remove-duplicates lst)
  (define seen (make-hasheqv))
  (define (ins val)
    (hash-set! seen val #t)
    val)
  (let aux ((lst lst))
    (cond ((null? lst) lst)
          ((not (pair? lst)) (if (hash-has-key? seen lst) '() (ins lst)))
          ((pair? (car lst)) (let ((a (aux (car lst))))
                               (if (null? a) ; if the only element is elmininated
                                   (aux (cdr lst))
                                   (cons a (aux (cdr lst))))))
          ((hash-has-key? seen (car lst)) (aux (cdr lst)))
          (else (cons (ins (car lst)) ; NB! order of evaluation in Racket is left to right but not in Scheme! 
                      (aux (cdr lst)))))))

;; test
(remove-duplicates '(a b a))                 ; ==> (a b)
(remove-duplicates '(a (a) b a))             ; ==> (a b)
(remove-duplicates '(a (b a) b a))           ; ==> (a (b))
(remove-duplicates '(a b (a b) b a))         ; ==> (a b)
(remove-duplicates '(a (a . b) b a))         ; ==> (a b)
(remove-duplicates '(a b (a b . c) b a . d)) ; ==> (a b c . d)
```

Comment: If I do something like this it should remove all the duplicates also right?

`(duplicates '(1 (2 (3 (2 (4 (5))))))`

EDIT: Yep that works perfectly, although the code is a lot more complex than I thought it'll be.